# Creation of authentication connection is failing

Tags: botframework

I am following the virtual assistant get started sample:

[Virtual asistant](https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/blob/master/docs/virtual-assistant/gettingstarted.md)

I am stuck on the step "Skill Authentication".

I tried to use the following command with all the arguments and generated botsecret for `--secret` argument.

```
msbot connect generic --name "Authentication" --keys "{\"YOUR_AUTH_CONNECTION_NAME\":\"Azure Active Directory v2\"}" --bot YOURBOTFILE.bot --secret "YOUR_BOT_SECRET" --url "portal.azure.net"
```

I still get the following error:

> Error: You are attempting to perform an operation which needs access to the secret and --secret is missing

Can someone tell me what am I missing?

Comment: When you provisioned your services using the powershell script (and therefore msbot clone command), it should've displayed a bot secret in the terminal window for you. If the bot is on Azure, you can recover the secret, which you can pass as the --secret argument to yoru msbot connect command. However if it's not on Azure, I'm afraid the secret might be lost...

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it does not appear it's in Azure portal. I was thinking it was here: to get botfilesecret from Azure portal go to https://ms.portal.azure.com/#, navigate to the resource group then on the left hand side blade under Settings click "Deployments" => Deployment Name link => Inputs -- HOWEVER it appears botfilesecret is not there. You possibly need to create a new Virtual assistant copy and run the command again and this time save the bot file secret